# React child component state not updating when new props are passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering a custom modal component that is displayed based on props passed in from a parent component. The prop `isVisible` is initially `false` and then updated in the parent component via a button. I'm checking the component state via the `console.log` statement in the render function. When the component is first initialized, it logs `false false` as expected but when the isVisible is updated, it returns `false true`. Why is the state not updating with the props?

```
class MyModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        createModalVisible:props.isVisible,
      };

   setCreateModalVisible = (visible) => {
     this.setState({createModalVisible:visible});
   }

   componentWillMount(){
     this.setCreateModalVisible(this.props.isVisible);
   }

  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.createModalVisible,this.props.isVisible);

    return (//modal stuff)
  }
}
export default MyModal
```

I get that this is probably pretty basic component lifecycle stuff but I couldn't figure it out from the docs and am fairly new to React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `constructor` and `componentWillMount` is only run once per component mounted in to the DOM tree the state wouldn't be updated on each props being passed down.

`this.state` is local for each component instance and needs to be updated with `this.setState()` to be able to use an updated state object on each render pass.

Use 
[componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) in which you can set the state to reflect the new prop being passed in for you to get what you need.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated. you should use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` instead.